# Netbeans 8.0 fresh install fails silently to start

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, netbeans-8

Just installed Netbeans 8.0.2 after uninstalling a previously working 7.4 installation.

The jdk is correctly set and indicated at setup time, installation finished successfully (although no start shortcuts installed as in Netbeans 7.4).

Now I issue a

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans
```

and the script silently churns for some seconds then returns with no error and nothing shown whatsoever.

`/usr/var/log/syslog` shows no error.

**EDIT**: found out there's a log file for Netbeans inside

> ~/.netbeans/8.0.2/var/log

it shows the following errors:

```
Log Session: Thursday, March 5, 2015 1:42:52 PM CET
System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905) (#8230772f5f18)
  Operating System        = Linux version 3.11.0-26-generic running on i386
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_75; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.75-b04; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_75-b13
  Java Home               = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = de_DE (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/criadis_us
  Current Directory       = /home/criadis_us
  User Directory          = /home/criadis_us/.netbeans/8.0.2
  Cache Directory         = /home/criadis_us/.cache/netbeans/8.0.2
  Installation            = /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/ide
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/extide
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/java
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/apisupport
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/webcommon
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/websvccommon
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/enterprise
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/profiler
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/harness
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/javafx
                            /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/classes:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/lib/dt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/core_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:253)
```

Comment: Did you install this as root? I wonder if its a file permission error (ie the netbeans process can't access what it needs). Check the file permissions in the netbeans install. I have successfully installed the 8.0.2 version on Linux (no root install) with no issues and can run fine

Comment: I actually installed it as root, however fixing the missing library worked so it should be good installing it as root.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems a problem between Ubuntu 64 bit system and JDK 32 bit installed.

A simple

```
apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

solved the missing library. The library I had was the 64 bit version:

```
locate libXtst
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```